# how to play radio through Loud Speaker in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I implemented Radio in my Windows Phone7 Application using Below specified code,Now I want to give additional option to play through Loud speaker,

How can I full fill this option Any idea? is it possible?

```
FMRadio.Instance.CurrentRegion = RadioRegion.UnitedStates;
FMRadio.Instance.PowerMode = RadioPowerMode.On;
FMRadio.Instance.Frequency =101.5 ;

if (FMRadio.Instance.SignalStrength == 0.0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please connect your phone to the headset.");
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{            
   MessageBox.Show("Error Message:-> " + ex.Message + "FM Radio is not connected");
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that programmatically.

Comment: @Toni Petrina - Did u have any proof or any reference link for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as there is nothing in [FMRadio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff707498%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that would allow you to do this.

The built-in Radio (accessible in the Music+Videos hub) does have this ability [if you tap+hold the station number](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/how-to/wp7/music/listen-to-fm-radio), but it's simply not available to developers.

It's also worth noting that WP8 devices don't have the radio enabled, [but that may change in the future](http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/26/4148200/windows-phone-8-update-fm-radio-support).